# preg_match_all - regexp pattern

Tags: regex

What pattern i could use in order to get integer value -> 1 from:

```
$digit = 'My messages (1 new)';
$pattern = '/^My messages ([\d]+) ([\w]+)/i';

preg_match_all($pattern, $digit, $match);
```

correct my code please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
$digit = 'My messages (1 new)';
$pattern = '/\d+/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $digit, $match);
```

useful links to learn regex

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-regular-expression-tips-and-techniques/
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: FYI, this would only match a single digit - if there were 10 new messages, it would only match the "1". Also, the /i is unnecessary as digits don't have any case.

Comment: Perhaps /\d+/ would work better? Just in case they have more than 9 new messages.

Comment: Rofl, i feel so stupid... Thank you very much... Can u please give me a link on good regular expressions lessons...

Comment: I think there is only one text `My Message($d new )` not the all message have different string

Comment: /g - doesnt works - it says unknown modifier, it works with /i

Comment: @Heihachi oops.. I think in JS :P

Comment: Thanks, in which cases /g (global match) is needed? And why it won't work in my case? can you explain pls.

Comment: `/g` works when we want to search in a paragraph, i.e. when `\n` or `\r` is there.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$digit = 'My messages (1 new)';
$pattern = '/\d+/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $digit, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$pattern = "/^My messages \((\d+) (\w+)\)/i';`

Comment: `$pattern = "/^My messages \((\d+) (\w+)\)/i';` doesn't work. You are using different quotes (`"` and `'`) in the same string